# MongoDB - recover from corrupted shard?

Tags: mongodb, sharding

How do I rescue a sharded  MongoDB cluster when one shard is permanently damaged?

I have a MongoDB cluster with 48 shards.  Each shard is a primary with one replicaset.  Due to Bad Planning (tm), one of the boxes ran out of filespace and died.  The other one, already close, then ran out of space too.  Due to bad circumstances (probably a compact() or repairdb() going on at the time, the entire shard was corrupted.

I stopped daemons, tried to repair, but it would not succeed.

So, the question is, how do I accept the loss of one shard but keep the other good shards?  With 48 shards, the los of one is only 2% of my data.  I'm okay with losing that data, but I have to get to a normal healthy state.

What do I do?

Answer (score 2):

ANSWER OBSOLETE, REDOING ANSWER:

1. Stop all daemons on all boxes.
2. change config files for primaries to make them come up as standalone instances.
3. use mongoexport or mongodump to dump that shard's data into a file.  Ensure that the file contains the collections you want.  Try to get it so it doesn't include the _id field.
4. when you have backups completed and moved off the boxes to appropriately safe locations, clean up.  delete all data files, etc., and essentially re-create your cluster.
5. Re-load your data from your data backups.

Note that when you do the re-creation of the cluster, you should probably prepopulate it with a certain / large number of chunks so the splitchunk processes doesn't take forever.

If you end up with unbalanced shards (lots of chunks in one, not another), pause, turn off balancer's throttle so it goes Real Fast, and once it's balanced again, restart reloading.